# Mostrar formato de fecha en "d-m-y" y guardar en una base de datos en formato "y-m-d"

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, datetime

Tengo que mostrar el formato `D-M-Y` pero se de debe guardar en la base de datos de MySQL, `Y-M-D`. Estoy usando *Bootstrap* para el calendario de fechas y *PHP* para realizar los mantenimientos a la tabla.

Código *HTML* y *PHP*:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Fecha Inicio :</label>
    <div id="datetimepicker1" class="col-xs-3 input-group">
        <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" class="form-control" id="fecIni" name="fecIni" ></input>
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="fa fa-times" data-date-icon="fa fa-calendar" ></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al momento que modifiqué el `data-format` a **dd-mm-yyyy**, sí, visualizo dicho formato, pero me produce un error al guardar y es por el tipo de formato ingresado.

No obstante, cuando le quito el `data-format` se muestra también con formato **dd-mm-yyyy**, pero no puede ser guardado.

Para los mantenimientos utilizo *Stores Procedures* y la fecha está declarada como `DATETIME`.

Comment: Podrías checar esta respuesta de SO en Ingles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Gracias,me sirvio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza las funciones de fecha nativas de **PHP**. Recoge primero el valor de tu input:

```
$fecha = $_POST['fecIni'];
```

Después se haría una conversión de fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
$fechaBD = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha));
```

Al final la variable `$fechaBD` es la que se insertaría en *Base de Datos*.

Fuente de información:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

bueno, tengo un metodo que puede funcionar, aunque posiblemente haya otro mas simple, 
imagino que antes de guardar tu fecha la recibes por post

```
$fecha = $_POST['fecIni'];
```

bueno, entonces dividela y crea una nueva variable con la fecha en el formato Y-m-d

el codigo seria algo asi....

```
$fecha = $_POST['fecIni'];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}";
```

y al momento de hacer tu insercion solo ocupas la variable **$_fecha** y deberia insertar en formato "Y-m-d"

Espero te sirva amigo aunque repito, podria haber una funcion incluso mas simple... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes transformar fechas de esta manera.

```
$fechaBD = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['fecIni']));
```

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede ayudar, es mucho más completo ya que incluye la zona horaria.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$zonaHoraria = date_default_timezone_get();
$horaFecha = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Checa la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) para más información